# Computer speed is very slow due to drive C is full

Tags: speed, cpu-speed

How to deal with slow speed problem due to no space in hard disk. My C drive is almost full. Only 1gb left. Computer RAM is 8gb.[image]

Comment: Get bigger disk or remove some content.

Comment: Other than this? I tried to remove programs. Unfortunately, all data is important. By integrating bigger hard disk, how can this problem resolved?

Comment: As simple as it seems, @MátéJuhász is right, these the are the options. You may run a cache cleaner like CCleaner...

Comment: Move the important data to the other drives?

Comment: Your data may well be important, but why do they need to reside on `C:`? As a quick fix, you can free space very quickly by moving your page file to `E:`. And of course make sure your back-ups are up-to-date before you do anything.

Comment: IMHO the best tool for quickly finding files that are filling up your  HDD is windirstat -> https://windirstat.net/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.  As to the reason this question is too broad, you are asking us to solve a problem, but you have not identified the cause of the problem.  If your system is full because of a page file, then the answer to this question is to disable or move the page file, otherwise, the answer would be something else entirely.  Your question as is cannot be answered here at Superuser.  Using something like WinDirStat and update your question.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention which operating system you're running, but I'll assume it's Windows.  It's possible you might have a hidden file in the root of C: called "hiberfil.sys".  This is for hibernation, so you can get rid of it if you don't plan to use that feature.  To see if it's there, open a command prompt and run `dir /ah C:\`.  If you see hiberfil.sys, open an **elevated** command prompt and run `powercfg -h off`.  Note that this will only buy you some time.  Your C: drive will fill up again eventually, so your long term strategy needs to involve moving some data away from C:\ onto another disk.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you check C: drive with Space Sniffer tool. I believe you will find redundant data to remove. Check it here: http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/